# any solution to take snapshot of a video in videovew ?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

hi can anyone tell me how to take snapshot of a video being played in the videoview. the snapshot gives blank image, or any method to grab the current frame of video, i want to pick the current frame, Anyone can help plz

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient solution will be [MediaMetadataRetriever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html). 
First of all call

> setDataSource(FileDescriptor fd)

Yes it's quite a tricky method. Sometimes it requires complicated solution. Here is an example:

```
public void setVideo(Uri videoPath) {
    videoUri = videoPath;
    File file = new File(videoPath.getPath());
    ParcelFileDescriptor pfd;

    FileDescriptor fd = new FileDescriptor();
    try {
        pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_WRITE);
        fd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();
        metadataRetriever.setDataSource(fd);           
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

to set the video you want to work with. Secondly use this method:

> getFrameAtTime(long timeUs)

to extract a frame. Keep in mind you should use **microseconds** as parameter

Comment: Please post all your Logs here

Comment: I m having problem in setDataSource(). . . Can u please give some sample example for my assistance. . .

Comment: throwing exception: file not found in FileNotFoundException, Pllication stopped working